# How To Show DataGridview Updated After insertion Or Updation

Tags: c#, datagridview

How To show Data Immediately In Data Grid View That is inserted Or Updated. I have to Re Start The Project To Show That Data.I Used **Update()** And **Refresh()** But not working for me

`private void UpdateDebtbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = ForConnection();
            conn.Open();
            using (conn)
            {
                if (paytextBox.Text != "")
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spdebth", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value =customerIDTextBox.Text.ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@text", SqlDbType.Int).Value = paytextBox.Text.ToString();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record updated");
                    spSelectAllCustomerDataGridView.Update();
                    spSelectAllCustomerDataGridView.Refresh();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: Set datasource again.

Comment: @Berkay Thank You Dear Its Working Now

Comment: using the DataTable of the DatatGridView have you tried dataTable.AcceptChanges();

Comment: @JohnG i set datasource Again adn its working Now Thank u Dear For Helping

Comment: Glad it works. This is a case of which way works best for you. Both get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Refresh` and `Update` methods are not used to refresh data, but re-paint `WinForms` control.

There are some ways of displaying data updated in DataGridView:

1. Use `BindingList` as data source, but this requires a object to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Update row on `DataGridView` manually
3. Rebind `DataSource`

Below is example for third point:

```
private void UpdateDebt(int customerId, int debt)
{
    var debts = (List<Debt>)spSelectAllCustomerDataGridView.DataSource;
    var item = debts.First(x => x.Id == customerId);
    item.Debt = debt;

    spSelectAllCustomerDataGridView.DataSource = null;
    spSelectAllCustomerDataGridView.DataSource = debts;
}
```

You have to rebind `DataGridView` to display changes.